# After changing Scripting Backend from Mono to IL2CPP app can't open sqlite database

Tags: sqlite, unity-game-engine

Everything works fine on PC but on android after changing Scripting Backend i began getting error after line:

```
 _connection.Open();
```

In try catch i got this error: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Mono.Data.Sqlite. UnsafeNativeMethods' threw an exception. --> System.DINotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'sqlite3'. Tried the load the following dynamic libraries: Unable to load dynamic library 'sqlite3' because of 'Failed to open the requested dynamic library (0x06000000) dlerror() = dlopen failed: library "sqlite3" not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by copying these files

```
I18N.MidEast.dll
I18N.Other.dll
I18N.Rare.dll
I18N.West.dll
Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll
Mono.Data.SqliteClient.dll
System.Data.dll
```

from Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0
to the project's \Assets\Plugins path.